# Do you need ssl to access Azure AD Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-ad-b2c

Using this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/) to connect to azure ad directory and wanted to know if it was necessary to use ssl?

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part of the tutorial, specifically, you are asking about?

Comment: Step 1: https://localhost:44321/... I'm thinking because they are sending back a token they want it sent over an ssl connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all authentication endpoints should be HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should *always* secure any API or web site with TLS (in this case, using HTTPS). It is increasingly easy to obtain and use certificates.

For development scenarios, you may use an HTTP reply URL only if the host is `localhost`.